# 'git pull origin mybranch' leaves local mybranch N commits ahead of origin. Why?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull

I just observed something odd about `git pull`, which I don't understand.

On Friday, I worked on a local branch. let's call it `mybranch`. Before leaving the office I pushed it to origin (which is my github repo): `git push origin mybranch`.

Yesterday at home, I `pull`ed mybranch to my laptop, did some more coding, and then pushed my changes back to github (origin).

Now I'm at work again, and tried to pull the changes from yesterday to my work machine (I didn't change anything in my work place's local repo over the weekend):

```
git pull origin mybranch
```

that caused a fast forward merge, which is fine. I then did a `git status`, and it said:

```
# On branch mybranch
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mybranch' by 6 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Huh? How can it be 6 commits ahead when I didn't even touch it over the weekend, AND just pulled from origin? So I ran a `git diff origin/mybranch` and the diffs were exactly the 6 changes I just pulled from remote.

I could only "fix" this by running `git fetch origin`:

```
From git@github.com:me/project
af8be00..88b0738  mybranch -> origin/mybranch
```

Apparently, my local repo was missing some reference objects, but how can that be? I mean, a pull does a fetch already, and I didn't work on anything except that branch, so a `git fetch origin` and `git fetch origin mybranch` should have the same result?

Should I always use `git pull origin` instead of `git pull origin branchname`?

I'm confused.

Comment: I've noticed this too; a `git push` will also seem to solve it (reporting "all up to date").

Comment: `git config --get-regexp br.*` can tell you if your config has a a local branch is tracking another branch

Comment: Can you type `git config branch.master.remote yourGitHubRepo.git` in your workRepo and check (at the next `git pull origin`) if the status remains with a 'ahead' warning?

Comment: it's not set (empty output). but `git remote show origin` shows me that origin points to my GitHub repository, so that should be okay I guess?

Comment: git remote alone (showing the right address for GitHub repo) **is not enough**. To avoid having an "`Your branch is ahead`" warning message after a `git pull`, you need first to *also* **define the remote name for a branch**. Hence my suggestion: type `git config branch.master.remote yourGitHubRepo.git`, then try a `git pull` and a `git status` and see if the issue remains.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll try that ASAP (there is nothing to push or pull ATM) and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @VonC thanks buddy, you just helped me git rid of my branch is ahead error! +1

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`git pull` calls `git fetch` with the appropriate parameters before merging the explicitly fetched heads (or if none the remote branch configured for merge) into the current branch.

The syntax: `git fetch <repository> <ref>` where `<ref>` is just a branch name with no colon is a 'one shot' fetch that doesn't do a standard fetch of all the tracked branches of the specified remote but instead fetches just the named branch into `FETCH_HEAD`.

**Update:** for Git versions since 1.8.4, if there is a remote tracking branch which tracks the ref that you asked to fetch then the tracking branch will now be updated by `fetch`. This change has been made specifically to avoid the confusion that the previous behaviour caused.

When you perform `git pull <repository> <ref>`, `FETCH_HEAD` is updated as above, then merged into your checked out `HEAD` but none of the standard tracking branches for the remote repository will be updated (Git <1.8.4). This means that locally it *looks* like you are ahead of of the remote branch, whereas in fact you are up to date with it.

Personally I always do `git fetch` followed by `git merge <remote>/<branch>` because I get to see any warnings about forced updates before I merge, and I can preview what I'm merging in. If I used `git pull` a bit more than I do, I would do a plain `git pull` with no parameters most of the time, relying on `branch.<branch>.remote` and `branch.<branch>.merge` to 'do the right thing'.

Comment: +1 That's really a good explanation! I knew the explanation was hiding somewhere inside of 'git help fetch' but couldn't get it out...

Comment: +1. Good post, with an approach similar to http://gitster.livejournal.com/28309.html

Comment: So would a `git fetch` after a `git pull <repository> <ref>` fix the issue since the fetch would update the standard tracking branches? Also, thanks for this answer, starting to make sense :)

Comment: I ran into this issue too and you would need to do `git fetch` followed by `git merge origin/master master`.

Answer (score 3):

What does `git remote -v show` returns when it comes to origin?

If origin points to github, the status should be up to date, and not ahead of any remote repo. At least, with the Git1.6.5 I am using for a quick test.

Anyway, to avoid this, define explicitly the remote repo of master branch:

```
$ git config branch.master.remote yourGitHubRepo.git
```

then a `git pull origin master`, followed by a `git status` should return a clean status (no ahead).
Why? because the get fetch origin master (included in the git pull origin master) would not just update `FETCH_HEAD` (as [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin/1743870#1743870)), but it would *also* update the "remote master branch" within your local Git repository.
In that case, your local master would not seem anymore to be "ahead" of the remote master.

---

I can test this, with a git1.6.5:

First I create a workrepo:

```
PS D:\git\tests> cd pullahead
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> git init workrepo
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tests/pullahead/workrepo/.git/
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> cd workrepo
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> echo firstContent > afile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> git add -A 
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> git commit -m "first commit"
```

I simulate a GitHub repo by creating a bare repo (one which can receive push from anywhere)

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> cd ..
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> git clone --bare workrepo github
```

I add a modif to my working repo, that I push to github repo (added as a remote)

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> cd workrepo
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> echo aModif >> afile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> git ci -a -m "a modif to send to github"
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> git remote add github d:/git/tests/pullahead/github
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> git push github
```

I create a home repo, cloned of GitHub, in which I make a couple of modifications, pushed to GitHub:

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo> cd ..
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> git clone github homerepo
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> cd homerepo
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\homerepo> type afile.txt
firstContent
aModif

PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\homerepo> echo aHomeModif1  >> afile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\homerepo> git ci -a -m "a first home modif"
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\homerepo> echo aHomeModif2  >> afile.txt
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\homerepo> git ci -a -m "a second home modif"
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\homerepo> git push github
```

I then clone workrepo for a first experiment

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo4> cd ..
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> git clone workrepo workrepo2
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tests/pullahead/workrepo2/.git/
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> cd workrepo2
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo2> git remote add github d:/git/tests/pullahead/github
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo2> git pull github master
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From d:/git/tests/pullahead/github
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating c2763f2..75ad279
Fast forward
 afile.txt |  Bin 46 -> 98 bytes
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

In that repo, git status does mention master geing ahead of '`origin`':

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo5> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

But that is only `origin` is not github:

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo2> git remote -v show
github  d:/git/tests/pullahead/github (fetch)
github  d:/git/tests/pullahead/github (push)
origin  D:/git/tests/pullahead/workrepo (fetch)
origin  D:/git/tests/pullahead/workrepo (push)
```

But if I repeat the sequence in a repo which has an origin to github (or no origin at all, just a remote 'github' defined), status is clean:

```
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo2> cd ..
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> git clone workrepo workrepo4
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead> cd workrepo4
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo4> git remote rm origin
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo4> git remote add github d:/git/tests/pullahead/github
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo4> git pull github master
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From d:/git/tests/pullahead/github
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating c2763f2..75ad279
Fast forward
 afile.txt |  Bin 46 -> 98 bytes
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
PS D:\git\tests\pullahead\workrepo4> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

If I had only `origin` pointing on `github`, `status` would be clean for git1.6.5.
It may be with a 'ahead' warning for earlier git, but anyway, a `git config branch.master.remote yourGitHubRepo.git` defined explicitly should be able to take care of that, even with early versions of Git.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this. The origin remote already points to my GitHub repo. I cloned that project from a GitHub url and my local master branch is tracking origin/master. As for the mybranch, I'm pretty sure I created it off the origin/mybranch branch, which should track it automatically. But still, maybe this is the problem? That the local mybranch doesn't actually track origin/mybranch? PS: I'm using git 1.6.1 (via MacPorts).

Comment: Is there a git command which let's me see if a local branch is tracking another branch? I can't find it in the man pages.

Comment: You can see which remote branches are tracked with `git remote show origin`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you careful to add all of your remote (except `origin` which comes with your original clone) using `git remote add NAME URL`?  I've seen this bug when they've just been added to the git config.

Comment: I did this when cloning the repo. I didn't do this with each branch, however. For e.g. mybranch I would first fetch from origin, then `git checkout -b mybranch origin/mybranch`. According to the man page of git-branch, the origin/mybranch is the start point, and furthermore, it states for --track: "... Use this if you always pull from the same upstream branch into the new branch, and if you don't want to use "git pull <repository> <refspec>" explicitly. This behavior is the default when the start point is a remote      branch."