# How can I recover a lost commit in Git?

Tags: git

First, got "your branch is ahead of origin/master by 3 commits" then my app has reverted to an earlier time with earlier changes.

How can I get what I spent the last 11 hours doing back?

Comment: Did you already look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277077/why-is-git-telling-me-your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-11-commits-a or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432579/git-your-branch-is-ahead-by-x-commits or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342618/git-your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-3-commits ?

Comment: If you are using SourceTree or other Git GUI apps, head [down there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git/78189735#78189735).

Answer (score 1155, accepted):

[`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is your friend. Find the commit that you want to be on in that list and you can reset to it (for example:`git reset --hard e870e41`).

(If you didn't commit your changes... you might be in trouble - commit early, and commit often!)

Comment: So the problem actually occurred when I tried to commit... git reflog returns ": HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from following-users to ma....HEAD@{1}: commit: yo.... HEAD@{2}: commit: updated a ton....HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to following-u...how can I revert back to one of those last three?

Comment: Take a look at `git log HEAD@{1}`. If that looks like the right series of commits, then you can `git reset HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: Only if the codes are staged (using git add), they are kept in git and can be found back easily using commands like `git fsck --lost-found`.

Comment: Accidentally dropped a commit I should have kept when rebasing. This totally saved me from redo-ing a couple hours worth of work.

Comment: Be careful using `--hard`. [Uncommitted changes will be lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568936/what-is-difference-between-git-reset-hard-head1-and-git-reset-soft-head).

Comment: Do lost commits get auto-deleted after a certain period of time?

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 git-gc eventually cleans up old reflog entries, and once nothing references a commit its objects will eventually be cleaned up too. The conditions under which the reflog is cleaned up can be set via git-gc's config options https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt-gcreflogExpire (at the time of this comment, the default expiry for reflog entries is 90 days for commits which are reachable, and 30 days for commits which are unreachable from current tips).

Comment: My particular issue was that I committed my changes to a feature branch I wasn't using anymore and then, after switching back to `main` and pulling an update of the repo, those commits were seemingly gone. For me, merging my committed changes from the feature branch into `main` fixed the issue.

Comment: You saved my life, this command is OP

Answer (score 203):

Before answering, let's add some background, explaining what this `HEAD` is.

## ***`First of all what is HEAD?`***

`HEAD` is simply a reference to the current commit (latest) on the current branch. 
There can only be a single `HEAD` at any given time (excluding `git worktree`).

The content of `HEAD` is stored inside `.git/HEAD` and it contains the 40 bytes SHA-1 of the current commit.

---

## ***`detached HEAD`***

If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that `HEAD` is pointing to a prior commit in history it's called ***`detached HEAD`***.

[image]

On the command line, it will look like this - SHA-1 instead of the branch name since the `HEAD` is not pointing to the tip of the current branch:

[image]

[image]

---

#### A few options on how to recover from a detached HEAD:

---

#### [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit. 
This command will checkout to a given commit. 
At this point, you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit.
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
# in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# Create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well. 
`git reflog`  will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

#### ***[`git reset --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your HEAD back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt)) you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range. 
The reset command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit. 
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in the history as well.

```sh
# Add a new commit with the undo of the original one.
# The <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

This schema illustrates which command does what. 
As you can see there, `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]

Comment: That just saved me many hours of work. I used "git reflog --date=iso" to see the date/time for each entry since I couldn't tell for sure without the timestamp.

Comment: for me, in `git reset --hard <commit_id>`, removing `HEAD` worked! 
+1 for graphical representation!!.

Comment: Just to mention: if you know the branch name: `git reflog <branchname>` can be quite useful, since you see the changes of just one branch.

Comment: Nice explanation. I tend to use `git cherry-pick <dangling-commit-hash>` on the branch where I want it to come to put it there.

Answer (score 60):

Another way to get to the deleted commit is with the `git fsck` command.

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

This will output something like at the last line:

```
dangling commit xyz
```

We can check that it is the same commit using `reflog` as suggested in other answers. Now we can do a `git merge`

```
git merge xyz
```

**Note:**
We cannot get the commit back with `fsck` if we have already run a `git gc` command which will remove the reference to the dangling commit.

Comment: This is the only answer that works if you haven't recently pointed at the commit in question, such as when you fetch a branch and then accidentally reset that branch elsewhere.

Answer (score 26):

This happened to me just today, so I am writing what came out as a lifesaver for me. My answer is very similar to @Amber 's answer.

First, I did

```
git reflog
```

to search for that particular commit's hash, then just copied that hash and did

```
git cherry-pick <hash>
```

from that branch. This brought all the change from that lost commit to my current branch, and restored my faith on GIT.

Have a nice day!

Comment: This is what I needed. To note, my lost commit was only seen in `git reflog`; I did not see it at all in `git logs`.

Answer (score 17):

First of all use git reflog to list all your commits even the lost commit

```
git reflog
```

Then use git log HEAD@{your_commit_number} to find the commit you are looking for. e.g

```
git log HEAD@{17}
```

Checkout into the commit after you find it with git checkout HEAD@{your_commit_number} e.g

```
git checkout HEAD@{17}
```

You may need to add and commit your changes

```
git add .
git commit -m"quuck_fix"
```

Then, you will have to create a temporary branch to restore the commit back to your branch

```
git branch temp
```

Finally, you will checkout into your existing branch and then merge the temporary branch.

```
#git checkout <your_existing_branch> e.g

git checkout main
git merge temp
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this,
This will show all commits recorded in git for a period of time

```
git reflog
```

Find the commit you want with

```
git log HEAD@{3}
```

or

```
git log -p HEAD@{3}
```

Then check it out if it's the right one:

```
git checkout HEAD@{3}
```

This will create a detached head for that commit. Add and commit any changes if needed

```
git status 
git add
git commit -m "temp_work"
```

Now if want to restore commit back to a branch lets say master you will need to name this branch switch to master then merge to master.

```
git branch temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

Here's also a link  specifically for reflog on a Git tutorial site:
[Atlassian Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog)

Answer (score 9):

If you cannot find your commit with `git reflog` and it happen that you were using **IntelliJ IDE** you can `right click on your project root folder -> Local History -> Show History` and revert your changes from there.

I messed up doing `git rebase` with `git push -f` and this truly saved me since the commit was dropped from the local and remote repositories.

Hope that saves someone's day

Cheers

Comment: Hey So I have VS running and I have the commit id of a commit ec101349 how can i filter my reflog with this id? is it possible?

Comment: I didn't know about this feature, this saved me a few hours of lost work!

Answer (score 2):

**The safest way is to**

1. Find commit head number for state you want to restore

`git reflog` or `git reflog | grep your_phrase`

2. Create new branch off it

`git checkout -b your-branch HEAD@{<your-number>}`

Answer (score 0):

I use this quite often and it's dumbfounding me how uncomfortable this still is in git GUI apps such as SourceTree, so I wrote a little utility to help me visualize the history and hidden commits directly in the UI.

These scripts will create (and delete) tags for `n` last items from the reflog.

#### Usage

```bash
# Create "HEAD-n" tags for n reflog items
./reflog-tag.sh 5

# With prompt
./reflog-tag.sh

# Delete all "HEAD-*" tags
./reflog-untag.sh
```

On Windows put the scripts somewhere in PATH, then in the repo

```
sh reflog-tag.sh [<number>]
sh reflot-untag.sh
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

[image]

##### `reflog-tag.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Usage:
# ./reflog-tag.sh <number>

# Usage with prompt:
# ./reflog-tag.sh
# Please provide the number of last commits you want to tag: <number>

# on Windows
# sh reflog-tag.sh <number>

# Number of last commits to tag
n=$1

if [ -z "$n" ]
then
  read -p "Please provide the number of last commits you want to tag: " n
fi

# Get the last n commit hashes along with their reflog selectors
entries=$(git reflog --pretty=format:'%h %gd' -n $n)

while read -r entry
do
  # Split the entry into commit hash and reflog selector
  commit=$(echo $entry | cut -d' ' -f1)
  ref=$(echo $entry | cut -d' ' -f2)

  # Extract the number from the reflog selector
  number=$(echo $ref | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')

  # Create a tag for the commit
  git tag "HEAD-$number" $commit
done < <(echo "$entries")

echo "Tags created successfully."
```

##### `reflog-untag.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get all tags that start with 'HEAD-'
tags=$(git tag -l 'HEAD-*')

for tag in $tags
do
    # Delete the tag
    git tag -d $tag
done

echo "Tags deleted successfully."
```

### SourceTree integration

Right click in the graph view to view and execute Custom Actions.

[image]

#### Define custom actions

Open Tools > Options > Custom Actions > [Add]

1. cmd `/c sh reflog-tag.sh`
2. cmd `/c sh reflog-untag.sh`

[image]