# Recover git commits to (no branch)

Tags: git, version-control

I made a commit while on the (no branch) branch then did a pull, realized I was on the wrong branch and did a 'checkout master' and another pull. I now can't find my original commit to push on the master branch and I can't switch to the (no branch). Is there a way to resurrect my commit or get the diff?

Comment: Maybe - does `git reflog` show the commit - you could the maybe pull it into a real branch?

Comment: @AdrianCornish this is likely to be the correct answer: please post it below for votes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover a lost commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) will list for you all the commits you did, and a (for instance) `git merge HEAD@{1}` will merge it back into your branch.

```
$ git reflog
734713b... HEAD@{0}: commit: fixed refs handling, added gc auto, updated
d921970... HEAD@{1}: merge phedders/rdocs: Merge made by recursive.
1c002dd... HEAD@{2}: commit: added some blame and merge stuff
```

From [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse):

```
<refname>@{<n>}, e.g. master@{1}
```

> A ref followed by the suffix `@` with an ordinal specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{1}`, `{15}`) specifies the n-th prior value of that ref.

Note that a `git rebase -i` would do the same.

The [Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) page mentions:

> It’s important to note that the `reflog` information **is strictly local** — it’s a log of what you’ve done in your repository.
>   The references won’t be the same on someone else’s copy of the repository; and right after you initially clone a repository, you'll have an empty reflog, as no activity has occurred yet in your repository.

The config `gc.reflogExpire` specifies when to removes reflog entries older than this time; **defaults to 90 days**.

Comment: This is often true, although can fail depending upon git reflog configuration.

Comment: Why do I remember reading something about the last 20 commits only - or am I wrong

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I came in this morning and after fixing some whitespace conflicts get everything merged in.

Comment: @VonC Thank you - really this is your answer - mine was really just a comment on what I roughly thought might work - you answer actually explains it and the credit belongs to you.

Comment: You JUST saved my life with this command!  GIT is awesome! (Awesomely complicated but ultimately saved the day!) - Thanks!