# How to modify master in Git (in this situation)

Tags: git

I am using git (from visual studio but I don't think that is that relevant) and I have come to have the following situation

[image: My current git history now]

As you can see there are four branches (BX) and several other commits in between. Also the master branch (M) -which is in red.

Well, due to my inexperience, I have gotten into the situation that the stable version of my program is in B3. I made some experimentation in B4 but I think that I will discard it. -I know how to do it, no problem there.

However- the master branch is in a completely different direction. The two commits toward it have things that I don't care about and that I absolutely don't want in my already working program.

So my question is - since "master" is supposed to be the stable release- how do I make master point to where B3 is???

This must be a really basic question but I trust in the advice of experienced people

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the current branch to master in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git)

Comment: Have you pushed master branch changes to remote already?

Comment: No, so far just locally

Comment: In this case @j6t answer is good for you

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution (*if these are all local feature branches you have created*) is to do the following:

1. `git branch -d B4`
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git reset --hard <SHA of B2's commit you want>`
4. `git checkout B3`
5. `git rebase B3 master`

This will delete branch `B4`, remove the commits from `master` that you do not want, and then replay all the commits from the `B3` branch that you want onto the head of `master`. Keep in mind you may need to resolve some conflicts during the rebase. When you finish resolving them, run `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Sorry but don't understand. I mean, yes 1 is deleting B4 and then you go to master. Then (3) the master will point at B2.  But after that, why 4 and 5?? I mean B3 would be already ON master (which is B2) so why do I need to rebase it?? why not just a fast forward merge??

Comment: You're absolutely right. A fast-forward merge would provide the same result as a rebase, without the need to create additional commits.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. When in 3) I make the master point to B2, what happens to the commits that previously went to master? are they erased?

Comment: Git uses a garbage collector that will eventually erase those commits, but typically they will stick around for a couple weeks. If you need to get them back and the garbage collector hasn't removed them yet, you can use `git reflog` to find out when the ref changed for master and use `git reset --hard <former reference name or SHA hash for master>` to bring master back to its original state before (3).

Comment: Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1) answer for a more in depth explanation of how to get commit changes back after a `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is

```
git branch -f master B3
git checkout master
```

This abandons the old master and moves it to B3.

Comment: Thank you. Not that I really care much for the commits of the old master but just to learn git theory... if I execute your commands, are the old master commits lost forever?

Comment: @KansaiRobot They are not lost immediately, but they will be garbage-collected after some time, typically 2 weeks. Then they are gone forever. Until then, you can recover them with [various tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git).

Comment: Thanks. But what if there is a Tag in master, and then execute `git branch -f master B3`? in that case, will the commits stay? or are they erased?

Comment: @KansaiRobot When there is a tag that points at the old master, that commit is protected and will not be lost.