# Deleted all commits using 'push -f origin master' any way to restore?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I commited using 'git push -f origin master' and it deleted all my previous commits. Is there any way I can restore them or at least show all my previous commits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover a lost commit in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git)

Comment: Use `git reflog` and find your missing commits.  If you have an extant branches derived from `master` which contain the missing commits you could also use those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover from an erronous git push -f origin master?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3973994)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$ git reflog                   # show working tree, copy the last commit-hash that have all codes
$ git checkout <commit-hash>   # checkout to that commit, now you've all codes
$ git checkout -b new-master   # create a new branch named new-master & checkout.
$ git branch -D master         # delete your local master branch
$ git checkout -b master       # create master from current commit and checkout to master
$ git push -f origin master    # push all the codes to remote
```

Answer (score 0):

Use git reflog to see missing commits.

Then, find the commits you want and use git reset in order to reset them.

After reseting the deleted commits, then push the changes to the origin using git push origin master

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reflog from either your local git reflog or remote repository and find the commit that you want to revert to;

```
git reflog //at local level
git reflog show remotes/origin/master // at remote level:
```

The reflog shows a list of all changes to HEAD in reverse chronological oder. The has in the first column is the value of HEAD after the action on the right was performed. So you can find the commit hash and checkout the commit you want to return your repo to by checking out its hash

```
git checkout <commit-hash>
```

Create a temporary branch off from the commit

```
git checkout -b new-master
```

Push it back to the remote repository.

```
git push -f origin master
```

However this will have fixed your remote master but note that your local master is still the one you have introduced destructive changes, so you can either delete it with following command if you don’t need the changes in it.

```
git branch -D master ,
```

or you may need to do something like cherry-pick all the commits that were lost.

PS: You can also find ***git fsck*** more suitable for recovering lost commits