# git commit --amend remove last commit without change anything on process

Tags: git

I've tried to change my last commit message so I did `git commit --amend` after that I didn't change anything, close my editor and my last commit is gone, how can I retrieve?

EDIT:
You can solve that problem using the information of comments about. On my problem `git reflog` and `git checkout HEAD{0}` solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover a lost commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git)

Comment: check `git reflog`.

Comment: How do you check the commit is gone?

Comment: Sorry for late response guys, @Mako212 was correct I don't realize what is happen and couldn't figure out how to solve my problem with the solution of previous post, so I use `git reflog` and then `git checkout HEAD{0}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works for you to use

```
git reset --hard id_commit
```

or

```
git revert id_commit
```