# Restoring accidentally lost commit due to detached Head

Tags: git, git-branch, git-detached-head

I lost my code after switching to another branch (thought that I pushed it, but head was detached)

I switched from master to origin/somebranch
Did some work there
Then I had to quickly fix something in master, so I did
git add -A
git commit -m "some commit"
git push
git checkout master

I did it pretty fast, so I didn't read the message about head being detached... So a result when I switched back to somebranch, my changes were not there... 
Are my changes lost or there is a way to restore it?

Comment: Check the below link, this would definitely help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your commit is not lost, it would be at this point unreferenced by any branch (and, as such, candidate for garbage collection) but the reflog keeps a reference on it for some time (90 days by default, but you can check your config entry `gc.reflogExpire`) so you'll be able to recover it.

**How? First possible method** :

Condition : only if your terminal is still open with the output of previous operations.

If so, you'll be able to easily spot the hash of your commit :

```
git commit -m "Useful message here"
[master ec470f4] Useful message here
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Just recreate a branch at this point :

```
git checkout -b recovered-branch ec470f4
```

---

If, for any reason, you **do not** have this opportunity (terminal closed, did a `clear` in the meantime, anything), no worries :

**Second method, [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)**

```
git reflog
```

lists all previous positions of `HEAD`, so just get the commit hash you want there and use the same command to recreate your branch.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the reflof and find your commit and use that ID to create a new branch or move an already existing branch

```
git reflog
git branch -f some-branch the-id-of-the-revision
```