# Accidentally set wrong upstream branch

Tags: git

## How did that happen ?

I simply wanted to rename two of my git branches, local and remote. For the sake of understanding, let's say I wanted to rename the branch `EVOL` to `DEV`, and the branch `DEL` to `DELIVERY`.

To do so, I used the commands decribed [here](https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/). It's quite simple. Firstly, I did, while in `EVOL`

```
git branch -m DEV
git push origin :EVOL DEV
git push origin -u DEV
```

Using `gitk`, I saw the change was effective, and did everything I wanted. So, to rename my second branch, I did the following commands (still in the now-called `DEV` branch)

```
git branch -m DEL DELIVERY
git push origin :DEL DELIVERY
git push origin -u DELIVERY
```

Here is where I failed. I should have done the last command in the `DELIVERY` branch, except I did not change, I was trying to be quick, and I didn't see the instruction on the webpage.

## Consequences and problem

The `DEV` branch looks just like I wanted: same old `EVOL` branch, with a new name. However, the `DELIVERY` branch is just wrong, where I believe another branch was, months earlier than where `DEL` was. To be honest, I don't remember the use of the branch where `DELIVERY` is now, but ideally I would like to revert here as well whatever there was, to keep a clear history. Worse, it looks like I have lost track of my old `DEL` branch with its commit. I am unable to find them using `gitk --all`.

Since I realized my mistake, I didn't dare to try something, by fear of losing the old `DEL` commits. The last command I executed is that infamous `git push origin -u DELIVERY`

## Question

Is it possible to revert that last command `git push origin -u DELIVERY` and/or to retrieve my commits that were on the `DEL` branch ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the `DELIVERY` branch is just wrong"*? Besides, I can't imagine how `git push origin -u DELIVERY` should be related to you losing the `DEL` branch.

Comment: @alfunx To be honest, I don't know how precisely what happened to `DELIVERY`, even less explaining that in english. I edited my post to be as precise as I can.

Comment: Okay. Again, I don't think the push is related to the lost branch. Have a look at this to recover `DEL`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git

Comment: @alfunx Couldn't find my lost commits with reflog either unfortunately. Well, it will teach me a lesson I think. I am lucky enough that it was the `DEL` branch, I still have the last delivery on hand, will try to just fetch it and push again, but with another name, just in case.
Perhaps `DELIVERY` was an already existing branch (I checked before manually by scrolling `gitk --all`, might have missed it), causing all of this trouble.

Comment: If the `DELIVERY` branch existed before, `git branch -m` should have failed.

Comment: As @alfunx said, `git branch -m` should complain if you are trying to rename a branch to an in-use name. I wonder if this was a case-sensitivity issue. Git itself believes that branch names are case sensitive, i.e., `Hello` and `hello` are two different branches. So you can have one of each. Windows and MacOS file systems, by default, say that you *can't* have one of each: one just overwrites the other. When Git and these file systems fight, one of them wins, but there's no predicting who.