# How to get remove git commit?

Tags: git

I have mistakenly delete last commit using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

There is any process to get the previous data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+hard+reset

Comment: I have committed multiple files with the same messages. how to remove those commit from others? @php

Comment: That's a different question, don't ask it in comments, ask as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't delete the last commit; you merely reset the current branch to point to that commit's parent. `git reflog` will tell you what you previously had checked out; you can simply `git reset --hard` back to that commit.

Comment: Thank you. I have committed multiple files with the same messages. how to remove those commit from others? @Patrick Stevens

Answer (score 1):

Check out [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), which allows you to see the commits that are not referenced by any branch. It is well explained by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git)