# Commit on HEAD missing

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have some problem after commit and checkout on another branch.

First I commit last update development and position commit on HEAD, but HEAD is not a branch.
So I checkout branch master and check on history log there are no results from my last commit.

Does anybody know how to get my last commit ?
I already checkout HEAD but same result, like `master` branch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you indeed made a commit, then `git reflog` should help you find it.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your branches: recent repositories could use `main` instead of `master`:

```
git branch -avv
git status
```

Then switch to the appropriate branch to find back your commit:

```
git switch anBranch
```

As commented, if none of those branches reference your commit, [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) should still be able to list said commit: you can then [recover it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10099258/6309).