# Reset a Git download on pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

I recently  added a git connection to my pycharm project, this worked well until today, last time I used  it i haven't uploaded my changes so  they are only local saved, after starting pycharm I downloaded the git repository. A few minutes later I realised that the newest version was  on my pc and the download over written it with the older version, is there a way to undo this?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover a lost commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git)