# Lost Changes after rolling back the last push on git

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-push, git-pull

I rolled back my last push from git using the following commands:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
git push -f
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

The push was successfully deleted but I lost all the changes from file and the rest of the files from visual studio.
How can I get those changes back?

Comment: RIP (Rest in pieces). Hint, don't execute commands that you don't fully understand

Comment: You can probably recover your changes by using `git reflog`. If you search for `git reflog recover deleted commit` you will find lots of links to questions on this site that describe the process.

Comment: Do you still have the output of the command ?
You should have the sha of the commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover a lost commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git)

Comment: Check the reflog (`git reflog`) to see what the commit ID you are missing is. Then you can use that ID to set a branch or do other things.