# How Do I 'git fetch' and 'git merge' from a Remote Tracking Branch (like 'git pull')

Tags: git, git-pull, git-merge, git-fetch

I have set up some remote tracking branches in git, but I never seem to be able to merge them into the local branch once I have updated them with 'git fetch'.

For example, suppose I have remote branch called 'an-other-branch'. I set that up locally as a tracking branch using

```
git branch --track an-other-branch origin/an-other-branch
```

So far, so good. But if that branch gets updated (usually by me moving machine and commiting from that machine), and I want to update it on the original machine, I'm running into trouble with fetch/merge:

```
git fetch origin an-other-branch
git merge origin/an-other-branch
```

Whenever I do this, I get an 'Already up-to-date' message and nothing merges.

However, a

```
git pull origin an-other-branch
```

always updates it like you would expect.

Also, running git diff

```
git diff origin/an-other-branch
```

shows that there are differences, so I think I have my syntax wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT [2010-04-09]:** I have checked a couple of times, and I'm definitely not on a different branch. Should my 'git fetch' followed by a 'git merge' (as shown above) do the exact same thing as a git pull? I will get some workflow showing the results of a git status etc.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You don't fetch a branch, you fetch an entire remote:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/an-other-branch
```

Comment: More details: `git fetch origin an-other-branch` stores the fetched tip in `FETCH_HEAD`, but not `origin/an-other-branch` (i.e. the usual ‘remote tracking branch’).

So, one could do `git fetch origin an-other-branch && git merge FETCH_HEAD`, but doing it like @Gareth says is better (or just use *git pull*).

Comment: so if origin has 1000 branches, you'd a remote branch for all of them?

Comment: Sure. If I've added a remote repository with 1000 branches to mine, and I ask what branches the remote has, it damn well **better** give me all 1000

Comment: will `git merge origin/an-other-branch` merge `origin/an-other-branch` into all the local branches that are set to track it ?  how can i merge into only one local branch ?

Comment: Git will only merge something into your currently checked out branch. This is mostly because it would be tricky to deal with conflicts in branches that you haven't got checked out.

Comment: So what does `git pull` (with no arguments) do -- which branch does it merge? Does it merge the remote-tracking branch corresponding to the *current* branch?

Answer (score 72):

### Selecting just one branch: `fetch`/`merge` *vs.* `pull`

People often advise you to separate "fetching" from "merging". They say instead of this:

```
    git pull remoteR branchB
```

do this:

```
    git fetch remoteR
    git merge remoteR branchB
```

What they don't mention is that such a fetch command will actually fetch *all* branches from the remote repo, which is *not* what that pull command does. If you have thousands of branches in the remote repo, but you do not want to see all of them, you can run this obscure command:

```
    git fetch remoteR refs/heads/branchB:refs/remotes/remoteR/branchB
    git branch -a  # to verify
    git branch -t branchB remoteR/branchB
```

Of course, that's ridiculously hard to remember, so if you really want to avoid fetching all branches, it is better to alter your `.git/config` as described in ProGit.

### Huh?

The best explanation of all this is in Chapter 9-5 of ProGit, [Git Internals - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) ([or via github](https://github.com/progit/progit/blob/master/en/09-git-internals/01-chapter9.markdown)). That is amazingly hard to find via Google.

First, we need to clear up some terminology. For remote-branch-tracking, there are typically 3 different branches to be aware of:

1. The branch on the remote repo: `refs/heads/branchB` inside the other repo
2. Your *remote-tracking branch*: `refs/remotes/remoteR/branchB` in *your* repo
3. Your own branch: `refs/heads/branchB` inside *your* repo

Remote-tracking branches (in `refs/remotes`) are read-only. You do not modify those directly. You modify your own branch, and then you push to the corresponding branch at the remote repo. The result is not reflected in your `refs/remotes` until after an appropriate pull or fetch. That distinction was difficult for me to understand from the git man-pages, mainly because the local branch (`refs/heads/branchB`) is said to "track" the remote-tracking branch when `.git/config` defines `branch.branchB.remote = remoteR`.

Think of 'refs' as C++ pointers. Physically, they are files containing SHA-digests, but basically they are just pointers into the commit tree. `git fetch` will add many nodes to your commit-tree, but how git decides what pointers to move is a bit complicated.

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin), neither

```
    git pull remoteR branchB
```

nor

```
    git fetch remoteR branchB
```

would move `refs/remotes/branches/branchB`, and the latter certainly cannot move `refs/heads/branchB`. However, both move `FETCH_HEAD`. (You can `cat` any of these files inside `.git/` to see when they change.) And `git merge` will refer to `FETCH_HEAD`, while setting `MERGE_ORIG`, *etc.*

Comment: Are you aware that your link to Git Internals is a link to this same question?

Comment: This has changed since Git 1.8.4. Now if there is a remote tracking branch which tracks the ref that you asked to fetch then the tracking branch will also be updated by the fetch.

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure you are on the local `an-other-branch` when you merge?

```
git fetch origin an-other-branch
git checkout an-other-branch
git merge origin/an-other-branch
```

The [other explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-mystery):

> all the changes from the branch you’re trying to merge have already been merged to the branch you’re currently on.
>   More specifically it means that the branch you’re trying to merge is a parent of your current branch
>
> if you're ahead of the remote repo by one commit, it's the remote repo that's out of date, not you.

But in your case, if `git pull` works, that just means you are not on the right branch.

Answer (score 3):

Git pull is actually a combo tool: it runs git fetch (getting the changes) and git merge (merging them with your current copy)

Are you sure you are on the correct branch?

Comment: I think the OP is in diff. branch, happens to me.

Answer (score 2):

these are the commands:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/somebranch somebranch
```

if you do this on the second line:

```
git merge origin somebranch
```

it will try to merge the local master into your current branch.

The question, as I've understood it, was you fetched already locally and want to now merge your branch to the latest of the **same** branch.