# Ramifications of forgetting slash in "git merge origin/branch"

Tags: git

Per [this article](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/), I've tried to get myself in the habit of fetching and merging explicitly when updating my working copy. However, today I made a typo when issuing the command:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git merge origin asdf
```

Note that I used a space instead of a forward slash on the merge command. Because it appeared to have had the desired effect anyway, I didn't notice until I had already pushed that it had added a strangely worded commit to the log:

```
commit 65f0037bed926c338cb95e7437e7f7f407028d9f
Author: Me <my_email@example.com>
Date:   Mon May 14 09:36:44 2012 -0700

    Merge branch 'asdf', remote-tracking branch 'origin' into asdf
```

Now I'm wondering if this actually had any negative side effects. It seems like it treated the arguments as two separate branch specs to merge into the current branch, and that "origin" would have implicitly expanded to "origin/asdf" — which is what I actually intended. At that point, I have no idea why it would even permit "Merge branch 'asdf' into asdf" to occur.

Was this just an embarrassing no-op? Or have I introduced a potentially problematic construct into my repository history?

EDIT: Output of `git cat-file commit 65f0037b`

```
tree 74ed9ead4b82e4e56bd5656ee10375f8f0fcb60d
parent 3bc2a37031a4a391aa4da64c22e3f55148cd23e2
author Me <my_email@example.com> 1337013404 -0700
committer Me <my_email@example.com> 1337013404 -0700

    Merge branch 'asdf', remote-tracking branch 'origin' into asdf
```

Comment: similar to this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602546/how-do-i-git-fetch-and-git-merge-from-a-remote-tracking-branch-like-git-pu

Comment: Can you do `git cat-file commit 65f0037b`? You may have performed an octopus merge or one of the commits may just have fast-forwarded and you may have got what you wanted with a misleading commit message. It's hard to tel from the commit description.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Unfortunately, about 45 minutes after I asked this question, I decided to err on the side of caution, and hard reset + redo the questionable merge. I realize that may render this question impractical to answer definitively, for which I apologize. However, the answer larsks gave, in conjunction with the fact that I know the default branch was in fact "origin/asdf" leads me to believe that the merge did indeed coincidentally (and awkwardly) accomplish what I had originally intended.

Comment: Unless you've deliberately set your prune time to very short and have gc'ed in the past hour, commit 65f0037b should still exist... not that it's important any more.

Comment: I edited it into the question. Not that it's important any more. But I'm curious what it would have told you.

Comment: @Neverender: It tells me that it only has one parent (which I can't otherwise see from the log) which means that it wasn't a true merge, just a regular commit with a misleading commit message. It may be that there was no actual change in the commit or, slightly more worryingly, the parent information was lost. Perhaps your local clone was up to date when you did this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the man page for the `merge` command:

```
   git merge [-n] [--stat] [--no-commit] [--squash]
           [-s <strategy>] [-X <strategy-option>]
           [--[no-]rerere-autoupdate] [-m <msg>] [<commit>...]
```

So, absent all the options, `merge` accepts a list of commits. If you're already on branch `asdf` and you type:

```
git merge asdf
```

...this is a no-op: merging a branch with itself means there's nothing to do.  If you type this:

```
git merge origin
```

Then `git` will look for the default branch associated with the remote named `origin`.  In the output of `branch -a`:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

`remotes/origin/HEAD` points to the default branch, so:

```
git merge origin
```

is equivalent to:

```
git merge origin/master
```

So assuming that the default branch on your remote is `master`, when you typed:

```
git merge origin asdf
```

You got:

```
git merge origin/master
```

If the default branch was `asdf`, you got:

```
git merge origin/asdf
```

Comment: Does not explain the remote tracking branch

Comment: Yes, I can say for sure that remotes/origin/HEAD did in fact point to origin/asdf in this example. I take this to mean that my original assessment (accidentally getting the desired result + awkward no-op) was accurate.