# Git look behind commits

Tags: git, github

I have a bare structure of my project. In few words, from local machine I make a push with some commit, go to main server and using `pull` take all changes.

I always do `git status` before pulling. And I always have a picture something like this:

```
On branch 6.0-rfc 
Your branch is behind 'origin/6.0-rfc ' by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

And I do git `pull` and everything is ok.

But, how can I view this 5 commits, for example, who made them, what files were changed and so on?

Comment: Just run `git log` after you complete the `pull`?

Comment: Yes, I can do it, but only after pull, but I have a situation that I need to look threw all this commits before

Comment: Got it. You'll want to `fetch` instead of using `pull` then. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inspect the commits before merging (done automatically by `git pull`), issue a `git fetch`, then inspect the `HEAD` of the branch (likely `origin/master`) that was updated by the fetch.

---

If you follow standard branch naming conventions (e.g. `master` for the local, `origin` for the remote), your new workflow could look like this:

```
git fetch origin  # Fetch all commits on the remote side, don't merge to master
git log origin/master  # Inspect the commits on origin's master
git merge origin/master  # Merge the commits into your local branch
```

When inspecting after the pull, you may also find it helpful to use [commit ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#Commit-Ranges).  To see only commits that the origin's master branch would add to your local master:

```
git log master..origin/master
```

Comment: Work day is off, I will check and write.

Comment: The last two commands should be `git log origin/master` and `git merge origin/master`.

Comment: @Ash- sorry, I'm assuming branch tracking of `master` to `origin`, so the `merge` is equivalent with or without the slash (see ["Ramifications of forgetting slash in “git merge origin/branch”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10589336)). I've changed the commands to be more explicit, though.

Comment: Oh, interesting! I've seen a lot of people accidentally make "origin" branches and so on by forgetting the slash; I didn't know git would infer like that. (We might have been on an older git version at that point, too.)

Comment: `git log master..origin/master` is what I really need!!Thanks!!