# git fetch shows nothing on console

Tags: git

We are following this model of using git:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

I'm trying to learn to use git fetch and git merge on the specific merge instead of just pulling.  For my question, what I did was made changes to a branch and pushed those changes to the branch.  I see those changes on github.  Then I switch to master to fetch those changes.  So I

```
git checkout master
git fetch  // terminal shows nothing
git fetch origin  // terminal shows nothing
```

Am I using the commands correctly for fetching?  I don't see anything on the console.  But then when I use a tool like SourceTree, and I fetch, it updates their tree and I can see the changes.

Assuming I get this next step to work, and I see the different changes were made, do I just do a `git merge <hash of the last commit or commit I want to merge in>`?  Thanks!

Comment: If everything is up to date, then `git fetch` will output nothing.

Comment: @dyng I don't think master is up to date since when I build, I don't have my latest features that I had on that last branch.  Does that make sense?

Comment: By default, if you have set an upstream for `master`, `git fetch origin` will fetch the code to `origin/master`(*not* `master`), I mean `origin/master` up to date when I say up to date. You can check it by `git diff master origin/master`. If not, maybe you have not set the upstream.

Comment: fetching is to update internal references and objects (inside .git ) from the repote repository, but to see the latest features you have to merge them. If you are already in your local master branch, you can do that : `git merge origin/master` (this will merge all the modifications implied by the remote "origin/master" in your local "master" branch)

Comment: if you get no output but the return code is 1, double check what `git config remote.origin.fetch` is. it may be invalid, which could cause that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the last part, as mentioned in "[Fun with FETCH_HEAD](http://gitster.livejournal.com/28309.html)", you can do:

```
$ git fetch git://repo.or.cz/stranger.git for-junio
$ git log -p ..FETCH_HEAD
$ git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

> Because "`pull`" is "`fetch + merge`", we are explicitly decomposing the operation into two steps.
>
> "`fetch`" leaves the information on the branch it found on the other side in **`FETCH_HEAD`**, which you can use as to name the commit object sitting at the tip of the branch.
>   "`git log -p ..FETCH_HEAD`" (notice the double dots) lets you view the commits he has but not in your branch with their changes in patch form to inspect what he did was sensible.
>   If you are satisfied, **you can use `FETCH_HEAD` to merge the commit in to your branch**.

(See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800214/6309))

As detailed in "[How Do I '`git fetch`' and '`git merge`' from a Remote Tracking Branch (like '`git pull`')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602674/6309)", you don't have to use FETCH_HEAD if you have a **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)** defined:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/an-other-branch
```

> `git fetch origin an-other-branch` stores the fetched tip in `FETCH_HEAD`, but not `origin/an-other-branch` (i.e. the usual ‘remote tracking branch’).
>   So, one could do `git fetch origin an-other-branch && git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

For the first part, make sure [your branch has an upstream branch set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309) to your remote upstream repo.

Answer (score 25):

`git fetch` or `git fetch origin` are fine, but if there is nothing to do, nothing is displayed.

You can use `git fetch -v` to be more verbose and display more informations

Comment: Straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might be using the Git repository HTTP URL and, depending on how the authentication and network are set up, you should use the Git URL instead.

If your Git-remote is called `origin`:

- First check that the assumption is correct, via `git remote get-url origin`.
  If HTTP, it will return something like `https://gitlab.yourdomain.net/repoGroupFoo/repoBar`.
- Go on the repository via Web, click on the "*Clone*" button and you'll see two URLs; copy the URL that uses *Git* protocol **instead** of HTTP.
  Or simply build it up starting from the HTTP URL components: like from `https://gitlab.yourdomain.net/repoGroupFoo/repoBar` ➡️ to `git@gitlab.yourdomain.net:repoGroupFoo:repoBar.git`.
- Change protocol via `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.yourdomain.net:repoGroupFoo:repoBar.git`

Try `git fetch` again.

Answer (score 1):

I found this because I was having a similar problem. I don't know the whys, but in my case I needed to explicitly name the branch which was updated:

```
$ git fetch [origin] [branch]
```

Let me explain--I use git for small scripts. I start the repo with `master`. After the script is deployed in production, and I still want to work on it, I will make a `dev` branch. But most projects just have one branch, or I just don't keep `dev` once merged.

Today, I updated remote master with a few minor changes, and wanted to update my local system with the changes. Out of habit, I just did `$ git fetch`. Nothing happened. Then I found your post. First, I added the project name (origin) and did `$ git fetch [origin]`. This updated both dev and master to the last time they shared a merge back in January. Then, OH! I ran `$ git fetch [origin] master`, and the changes were now downloaded.