# Git: how to $git pull [with password] on a command?

Tags: git, shell

I created a Deployment shell script to preform `$git pull`  for all of our websites, example :

```
#!/bin/bash

repo1=/var/www/html/website1
repo2=/var/www/html/website2

for repo in $repo1 $repo2
do
    (cd "${repo}" && git pull )
done
```

This is actually working but required to type password for any `$git pull` command.
we have 10 websites stored on 4 servers ,so its a bit of an hassle to type the password 40 times.

**Is there a simple way to add a password to the `git pull` command ?**

for example:

> $git pull -pw [password]

I know It's not the best and secured method but because I'm 1 of 2 persons authorized to access the servers , I don't really worry about someone revealing the password by watching Shell history.

Appreciate the help .

Comment: If you don't care about someone seeing the password in the history - why not _just_ add an ssh key and get rid of the need for a password completely? Users sharing accounts (implied) is the problem to solve here.

Comment: Can you instruct me how to do it? For the record im running the shell script from windows on remotes using plink

Comment: If you're only using passwords because you're not aware there's an alternative read up on how git uses ssh and ssh keys. For example [see this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), or the answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enter command with password for git pull?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull)

Comment: you can see the answer on this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31835965/365237

Answer (score 2):

From : https://superuser.com/questions/338511/how-do-i-disable-password-prompts-when-doing-git-push-pull

Generate a private/public key pair for password-less authentication.
For Linux, your keys are stored in `~/.ssh.`

If you already have files in `~/.ssh` that's named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, then you already have a key pair. Append the contents of your public key (that's `id_rsa.pub`) to the Git repository's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys file`.

`$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@git.repo:id_rsa.tmp
 $ ssh user@git.repo
 $ cat id_rsa.tmp >> .ssh/authorized_keys`

If you don't have the key pair, generate one with

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Read this for further instructions: http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-git-authorization/

Comment: I have done the direction above and now instead of _user@GitSource password_ , It requires _Enter passphrase for key '/home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa'_