# Is there any equivalent command to svn up in git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

```
svn up --username <mysusername> --password <mypassword>
```

Is there any equivalent command in git.

I want to put password in command like,

```
git pull --password <mypassword> origin master
```

Please advice me.

Comment: And why you cannot use git pull http ://username:password@repo.url....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter command with password for git pull?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at gitcredentials.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

From the documentation:

> Git will sometimes need credentials from the user in order to perform operations; for example, it may need to ask for a username and password in order to access a remote repository over HTTP. This manual describes the mechanisms Git uses to request these credentials, as well as some features to avoid inputting these credentials repeatedly.