# GitLab - Git pull command with username and password in CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have configured my CI pipeline to remote via SSH into a server and update the git repository there with the latest changes. However it fails. Because when the CI runs the `git pull` command, the response is : "could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com' "

Is there a way to run git pull which includes username and password in one single command?

I know the best way is to add the SSH key into gitlab variables to avoid asking for username and password, but that didn't work for me either. so my only option would be to provide username and password.

My gitlab-ci.yml file is like below:

```
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
   - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   - echo -e "$DEPLOY_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - ssh ubuntu@example.com "
      cd my_Project &&
      git pull
      "
```

Comment: Try `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa; ssh -A ubuntu@example.com "cd proj && git pull"`. Check - https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/

Comment: @HarishVed, I am now getting "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." error.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31835965/827715 @Benjamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order is incorrect. You add the ssh deploy key to the environment executing your CI job when you should add it inside the `example.com` environment executing the `pull` command.

It's like preparing a room with a chair and table and then entering the next room and expect you can sit down on the chair from the other room.

You should follow the instructions for [Deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys) and add the public key from the `ubuntu@example.com` user to your project deploy keys.

This should be all to make the last bit work.

### Note:

Your comment about: `echo -e "$DEPLOY_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa; ssh ubuntu@example.com" cd myProject && git pull` doesn't change the order, you still add the deploy_key to your current environment and then enter another one through ssh.

Comment: I got your point. I am now editing the "example.com" environment like: "    - echo -e "$DEPLOY_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa; ssh  ubuntu@example.com"
      cd myProject &&
      git pull
      " and still getting the same error which says : "could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com' " , Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What confuses me is that, if the orders are wrong, then why can I even connect to the server successfully? Because I can easily execute "mkdir" command on the remote serverwith the current order I have.

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried very hard by following every single step that is mentioned by gitlab official guide [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html) as well as @Stefan's suggestion, and still I wasn't able to run the `git pull` command on the remote server.

But I could connect to the remote server via SSH.

So, I end up storing the gitlab credential on the server to avoid interrupting the CI execution.

```
 $ git config credential.helper store
 $ git push http://example.com/repo.git
 Username: <username>
 Password: <password>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the below command to pull repo without credentials on GitLab CI

`git pull ${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}`

CI_REPOSITORY_URL -- is GitLab predefined environment url