# How to git pull with adding credentials SECURELY in bash or Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I want to `git pull` a project in GitLab via bash in Jenkins pipeline. It looks something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'develop',
                    credentialsId: '12345-123-123123-1f54-123141e67c',
                    url: 'ssh://git@gitlab.blabla:PORT/group/project.git'
                
                sh 'cd /var/www/project/'
                sh 'git pull origin develop'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But it requires inserting a username and password for every request. I find out about adding the credentials using these ways that stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull) SO discussion.

But using `git config credential.helper` will store the credentials in plain text which is it is not safe. And also cloning the project with the username and password in the git URL like this `https://user:pass@domain/repo` is also not safe.

Is there any way to do it securely?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can:

```
        stage('Cloning git repository') {
            steps {
                script {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/dev']], extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'my-repository']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'MY_GIT_CREDENTIAL', url: 'https://github.com/user/my-repository.git']]])
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Then just `cd my-repository`. You don't need to do that through a `sh` step. Jenkins will hand credentials through the checkout() step. You can use SSH keys or username and password stored into Jenkins credentials with that.

Best regards.

Comment: Is this script do a `git clone`? I need to do a `git pull`. How to do that?

Comment: Jenkins works using a distributed approach. If in the node Jenkins is ran there's already a workspace with the repository in it, the step will perform a `git fetch` and a `git pull`. If there's not, it will then clone it.