# how to implement the git pull in shell script without prompting username and password

Tags: git, shell, gitlab

I need to implement the "git pull origin Branchname" without prompting the username and password using the shell script.

**git pull origin Branchname**

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull

Comment: Keep in mind that if Gitlab requires username and password, but you do not want to type them, then you have to write them down somewhere, and suddenly the clear-text password exists not only in your brain, but also in machine readable form on your computer. That is a security flaw.

Comment: @j6t yes...but i added the one file in credential.helper but,still it asking username and password

Comment: This has nothing to do with the password issue, but: You should generally *avoid* `git pull` in scripts: it runs `git fetch`, then it runs a second (user configurable!) Git command. Scripts usually should not depend on user configuration. (If they *should*, that's when you want `git pull` after all...) So usually a script should run `git fetch`, then run `git merge`.

Comment: even i use git fetch,but still it is asking username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Clone your project using SSH.

   - I don't think you want this because you asked for a username and password. So I'll ignore it.
2. Clone your project with HTTPS setting the username and password in the URL itself.

   - EX: `https://username:password@gitlab.com/my-project`
   - If you already cloned the project, you still can edit the URL by: `git remote set-url origin https://username:password@gitlab.com/my-project` and you cab check your change by `git remote -v`

- Note: I would recommend using a specific token for this to limit the security impact. Read more here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/token_overview.html

Comment: i cant share the my username and password in https,as my whole team uses it.

Comment: Then create an access token for this as I suggested.
Look here on how to create one:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#project-access-tokens