# Ruby on Rails 3 + Git + Rspec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, rspec

Earlier, i was having a git issue where

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
#
```

I resolve it by following this other [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin) which said to try `git fetch origin`and this brought everything up to date.

NOW, when i run rspec on some test cases, i get

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ... No examples were matched. Perhaps {:if=>#<Proc:0x00000101888ab8@/Users/matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:50 (lambda)>, :unless=>#<Proc:0x00000101888a90@/Users/matthew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:51 (lambda)>} is excluding everything?
```

Finished in 0.0001 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

Can anyone clarify what went wrong? Did the git fetch command mess up some configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` does not affect your working directory. There's probably something else going on here.