# git fetch vs. git fetch origin master have different effects on tracking branch

Tags: git, branch, git-fetch

This is mostly of the nature of a curiosity as I'm trying to get familiar with Git. I have looked at the documentation for 'git fetch' but I don't see an obvious explanation for the below.  Thanks in advance, and apologies if this is howlingly obvious.

1) From a central repository, say GitHub, I clone a repository named `website` on each of two machines, `HostA` and `HostB`.

2) on `HostA`, I make a change to a file, say `README.txt`, and commit it.
At this point on `HostA`, the commits for branches `master` and
`origin/master` are, as expected different since I haven't pushed yet

```
git show master
git show origin/master
```

report different hashes (since `master` has the change and `origin/master` does not)

3) Once I push, they are after that the same.

---

4) Now, over on `HostB`, if I do the following:

```
git fetch
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

afterwards, on HostB `master` and `origin/master` report the same hash when queried with `git show`

BUT

if instead I had done, on `HostB`:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

at that point the hashes still differ.

```
git show origin
git show origin/master
```

report *different* hashes

The tracking branch `origin/master` isn't updated until I do a plain `git fetch`

Why is this?

Comment: Almost duplicate: (the fact that it is pull, not fetch, makes no material difference) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin-why

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If your branch has an associated [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309) that means its configuration is like:

```
git config branch.[branch-name].remote [remote-name]
git config branch.[branch-name].merge [remote-master]
```

The key part of **[`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)** which explain the difference between the two commands is:

```
<refspec>
```

> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source ref `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>   The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and **if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`**.

Let me repeat it:

**if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`**.
Knowing that:

- **`git fetch`** is equivalent to **`git fetch origin master:master`** (from the default value of your branch config), so it will update the remote tracking branch: **the destination of the refspec is specified for you**.
- **`git fetch origin master`** is equivalent to "`git fetch origin master:`", not to "`git fetch origin master:master`"; it stores fetched value of '`master`' branch (of remote '`origin`') in `FETCH_HEAD`, and not in '`master`' branch or remote-tracking '`remotes/origin/master`' branch (from [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071300/6309))
  In other words, **you didn't specify the destination of your refspec**

Comment: Hi VonC: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @Xoanon93 You are welcome. I always go back to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch when in doubt about remote tracking branches.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the messages you get back from `git fetch`.  In the first case, when you fetch without providing a refspec, you'll see that the remote tracking branches are updated:

```
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /depot
   c67d1c8..1941673  master     -> origin/master
```

Note how the message says that origin/master is updated with the master from the origin.

Now in the second case, where you specify the refspec, you get something altogether different:

```
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /depot
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

So when you specify the refspec, the remote tracking branch (origin/master) is NOT updated, only FETCH_HEAD.

The end result is that you'll appear to be ahead of origin/master when you're not really.  I can't imagine why this behavior would be desirable, but it's definitely an interesting little quirk of the fetch command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fast forward merge yourself, or use git pull.  You don't seem to understand that the purpose of git fetch is NOT to update your working tree. Fetch is meant to update your tracking branches.