# what does the syntax of git fetch mean

Tags: git

Suppose I do `git fetch origin` and I get the following output:

```
From origin
 * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      new        -> origin/new
```

What does this syntax mean ?
And sometimes it outputs different stuff, if I do `git fetch origin develop` I get the following output:

```
From origin
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
   f3beeb4..2b38122  develop    -> origin/develop
```

So here the syntax is different. Why? I'd appreciate a short description of each of these syntax's.

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys for not being more clear about my question. I'm actually interested in syntax/logic for these pieces:

```
 * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      new        -> origin/new

 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
   f3beeb4..2b38122  develop    -> origin/develop
```

And not for this one `git fetch origin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch` will connect to a remote repository. It will (per default) create "remote branches" inside the local repository, which are nothing but ordinary refs named like `remotename/branchname`.

If a new branch is detected on the remote repository, `git fetch` will create a new "remote branch":

```
 * [new branch]      new        -> origin/new
```

On the remote side (of the remote called origin) there was a new branch called "new". `git` therefore creates "origin/new" in this repository.

If the local "remote branch" is different from the branch on the remote repository, `git` will update it:

```
   f3beeb4..2b38122  develop    -> origin/develop
```

Here "origin/develop" was pointing to commit f3beeb4 but someone pushed to the remote repostitory and it therefore now points to 2b38122. Therefore `git` will update the "remote branch" from f3beeb4 to 2b38122.

If you specify an explicit branch name, `git` will store it in a special ref called "FETCH_HEAD". This will print like this:

```
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: thanks, can you please elaborate on why sometimes git shows this branch update `f3beeb4..2b38122  develop    -> origin/develop` and sometimes `* branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD` fetch_head update? What does the `* branch` mean in the latter syntax?

Comment: You should get the first message whenever there are new commits in the remote repository. (In this case `git` needs to update the local ref.) You should get the second message whenever you specify an explicit branch like in `git fetch origin develop`. (In this this explicity specified branch will be stored in FETCH_HEAD.) The first column of the output shows what kind of ref (branch/tag/etc) it talks about. the second column is the remote ref name and the third column is the local ref name.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch` updates the remote tracking branches (in this case `new` and `develop`).

`git fetch origin develop` stores fetched value of `develop` branch in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.

---

**Update:**

Found a stackoverflow post with good description for the same ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892517/git-fetch-vs-git-fetch-origin-master-have-different-effects-on-tracking-branch)).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [git-fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) makes it somewhat clear.

- `git fetch origin` is really `git fetch <repository>`.  You're telling Git where to fetch updates from, and it doesn't necessarily have to be a previously added remote - it could be a URL if you wanted.

  In your project, you can have as many remotes as you require; normally, though, only one remote is needed, and by convention it's `origin`.

  From the docs, if that's omitted, `origin` is the default unless you've got an upstream branch configured:

  > When no remote is specified, by default the `origin` remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch.

  If you've only got one remote, then this is mostly pointless to do; if you want to specifically fetch from a *different* remote, this is when you'd actually use this form.
- `git fetch origin develop` adds the `<refspec>` argument to the above command.  It's basically telling Git which ref to fetch, and which local ref to update.  It will store the result of this fetch inside of a [short-lived ref called `FETCH_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596689/1079354), *not* the branch directly.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch origin` basically updates your remote-tracking branches, which means that all remote repository branches are copied to your local repository.  The general command would be `git fetch <remote>`, where `remote` in this case is `origin`.  The output then displays the branches that were downloaded:

- `develop`, which is a and pointing to (remote) `origin/develop` (hence the `->`) and is a `new branch`
- `new` which points to (again remote) `origin/new` and is also a `new branch`

`git fetch origin develop` or in general `git fetch <remote> <branch>` does the same as above, but only fetches the specified `<branch>`, which is `develop` in your case.

*References:*

- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch/