# git ahead by myriads of commits, except it isn't

Tags: git, push

Can someone tell me why git repeatedly tells me I'm ahead a ridiculous number of commits (when in fact I'm not), and why I need to push in order for git to realize that?

```
> git status
# On branch dev
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 230 commits.

>git push origin dev
Everything up-to-date
```

Not such a big deal, but always getting a little adrenaline rush when pushing.

Comment: Adrenaline is a perfect replacement for caffeine. And it comes for free in your case ;)

Comment: I'd just delete the local branch and check it out again to solve the problem. Make sure you really pushed all your changes ;-)

Comment: @rami, my point is that there is no problem at all. it's just a regular inconsistence in git's reporting and I'm wondering whether this is do to a problem or just a random hickup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I get the `# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by x commits.` message, a `git fetch` usually fixes it for me.

Comment: yea I guess the `fetch` part of the `pull` is what fixes it for me too, but that still doesn't answer what's going on there! ;)

Comment: The message appears when the FETCH/HEAD pointer doesn't get updated during a `git pull`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1743870/1615761) explains it pretty well.