# Why does a 'git pull' not also update the remote branch I pulled from?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, pull

I have a forked repository, which is set up as a remote called `origin`, and it was forked from the original repository which I have push access to, called `upstream`.

I have checked out a patch release branch that is also stored in both repositories:

```
git branch -va

develop                              8888888
patch-branch-0.9.x                   1111111
remotes/origin/develop               8888888
remotes/origin/patch-branch-0.9.x    1111111
remotes/upstream/develop             8888888
remotes/upstream/patch-branch-0.9.x  1111111
```

I know that there have been merged pull requests in `upstream`, so **if I were to** run a `git fetch --all` then another `git branch -va`, I might expect to see:

```
git branch -va

...
patch-branch-0.9.x                   1111111
...
remotes/upstream/patch-branch-0.9.x  2222222
```

But I prefer to do a simple `pull` when updating my local branch. But, when I run the pull from the upstream:

```
git checkout patch-branch-0.9.x
git pull upstream patch-branch-0.9.x
```

Even though it reports:

```
From https://bitbucket.org/...
 * branch            patch-branch-0.9.x -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 1111111..2222222
```

It does not seem to update the status of the branch I pulled from, as I end up with:

```
git branch -va

...
patch-branch-0.9.x                   2222222
...
remotes/upstream/patch-branch-0.9.x  1111111
```

So even though my local branch has been updated to fast-forward to the remote upstream branch, I still have to run another `git fetch --all` to have `git branch -va` report the proper HEAD commit for my remote branch. (Even though it's the one I pulled from!)

Is this standard behavior? I was under the impression that the `pull` was simply a `fetch` followed by a `merge`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['git pull origin mybranch' leaves local mybranch N commits ahead of origin. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin-why)

Comment: @CharlesBailey I think you might be right - I hadn't encountered that question in my search. Specifically, from the accepted answer: `When you perform git pull <repository> <ref>, FETCH_HEAD is updated as above, then merged into your checked out HEAD but none of the standard tracking branches for the remote repository will be updated.`

Comment: I don't understand why that is though, or how to have git perform this operation automatically as part of a `pull`?