# why git fetch origin master failed?

Tags: git, github

Assume that my local repository is one commit behind the repository at github.

Then I commit one commit at the local repository

At this time

A------>commit 1  Github/master

A------>commit 2  local repository/master

I do the following steps to push commit 2 to github:

1. git fetch origin master
2. git rebase origin/master
3. git push origin master

But I got the following errors:

[image]
If I try to replace step 1 with `git fetch origin`, it works well

Then I tried `git fetch origin master:tmp`, a branch named tmp successfully created

So, My question is

why `git fetch origin master` sometimes works(in the case `git fetch origin master:tmp`), while sometimes not work in the case step 1?

Comment: Are you sure that `git rebase origin/master` was successful? It seems it wasn't. Maybe you could show the output of that.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Almost, but not quite, a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin-why/1743870#1743870). I'm guessing this is Git <1.8.4.

Comment: @Charles0429 please show the output of `git status` too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't about working or not, but about where you're asking git store what it downloads. If you omit the target in a refpec, you're asking git to store it in FETCH_HEAD. Thus, `git fetch origin master` is really `git fetch origin master:FETCH_HEAD`, and you're not touching `origin/master` or any ref at all (as you can see from the output, `master -> FETCH_HEAD`).

When you run `git fetch origin master:tmp` you're asking it to download the master branch (this is yet another layer, guessing that you want to deal with branches) and store it in a local branch named `tmp`. You would also see this mapping in the output.

If you want to update the remote-tracking branches, simply call `git fetch origin`. Calling the two-argument version of `git-fetch` is rarely something you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
```

you should just do

```
git pull --rebase
```

That will do the right thing.

Comment: It will do the "right thing" if master's upstream branch is set to origin/master, which may or may not be the case.