# Local and remote are identical. Then I pull from remote, and local is one commit ahead. What?

Tags: git

I occasionally get thrown by the behavior of git.  As I understand what I did below, I took the current version of the branch "public" on the remote repository, and replaced everything I had with it.  Nothing I was working on should still be there.

Then I pulled "public" from the remote repository again.  Voila!  Now I am one commit ahead, locally.

Can you tell me what happened?

[edit] People very properly asked me what version of git I am using.  2.1.4  I added a git --version to my code section below.

```
rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 ~/gogo/portal/gogo_flightTracker (public)
$ git status
# On branch public
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/public' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 ~/gogo/portal/gogo_flightTracker (public)
$ git reset --hard origin/public
HEAD is now at 30cdb42 Remove O/D from window display if 640px window.innerWidth or less

rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 ~/gogo/portal/gogo_flightTracker (public)
$ git status
# On branch public
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 ~/gogo/portal/gogo_flightTracker (public)
$ git pull origin public
\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\" get: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\" get: -c: line 0: `\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\" get'
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://rickhedin@github.com':
\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\" store: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\" store: -c: line 0: `\"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe\" store'
From https://github.com/gogoit/gogo_flightTracker
* branch            public     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded public to 2e65060cef06715081e54f776e0f7269e8d65ba7.

rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 ~/gogo/portal/gogo_flightTracker (public)
$ git status
# On branch public
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/public' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 ~/gogo/portal/gogo_flightTracker (public)
$

rhedin@RHEDIN1-T430 /cygdrive/c/work/150502
$ git --version
git version 2.1.4
```

Comment: What version of git are you using?  (It appears to be on Windows, and I don't know any of the specifics about Windows-ized git variants, but git's behavior with `pull` changed in git 1.8.4 so this probably matters to whoever *can* answer windows-specific items.)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['git pull origin mybranch' leaves local mybranch N commits ahead of origin. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741143/git-pull-origin-mybranch-leaves-local-mybranch-n-commits-ahead-of-origin-why)

Answer (score 1):

`git-pull` - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch

In the simplest terms, git pull does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.

You can do a `git fetch` at any time to update your remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes/<remote>/`. This operation never changes any of your own local branches under `refs/heads`, and is safe to do without changing your working copy. I have even heard of people running `git fetch` periodically in a cron job in the background (although I wouldn't recommend doing this).

A `git pull` is what you would do to bring a local branch up-to-date with its remote version, while also updating your other remote-tracking branches.

**Scenario:**

Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "`master`":

```
 A---B---C master on origin
     /
    D---E---F---G master
    ^
    origin/master in your repository
```

Then "git pull" will fetch and replay the changes from the remote `master` branch since it diverged from the local master (i.e., `E`) until its current commit (C) on top of master and record the result in a new commit along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes.

```
  A---B---C origin/master
 /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

**Git documentations:**

[git-pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

[git-fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

[git-merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: That's all correct and makes sense, *except*, he's apparently already done a fetch (via pull), then a `git reset --hard` to make his own branch match the one on origin.  Then he does another `pull` which does another `fetch` which should be a no-op, followed by another `merge` which should also be a no-op.  This assumes git version >= 1.8.4, though.

Comment: CloudFreezer's answer is so detailed and clear that I upvoted it.  (I think in your last diagram, you intend D to branch off of B, and C branches to H, not G.)  However, I think Torek's comment is correct.  I make my branch identical to the one on the remote repostory, and then do a series of no-ops.  The result should be identical to the remote repository.

Comment: My git version is 2.1.4 .